# How to clean up emails when replying in plain text?

Tags: mail.app, text-editor, plugins

I have a problem that I want to solve after many years of using Mac OS X Mail.app... I generally like to send plain text emails that are full width (format=flowed) and nicely indented for quote levels. When I receive emails that are in HTML my problems begin. I have the option of switching them into plain text *before* I hit reply (using alt+cmd+p) or *after* I hit reply (using shift+cmd+t). *Please no replies telling me to answer rich text emails with rich text replies. I want my cake on this one.*

If I switch to plain text *before* then generally the plain text will be wrapped to a specific width and also, in some cases I'll get lots of ">" where there should be vertical line quote indents.

If I switch to plain text *after* then I may loose a lot of the quoting levels. What I want is to be able to end up with clean flowed plain text replies with nice quote levels.

Has anybody else seen this behaviour or seen a plugin/app that can solve these issues?

Comment: vertical line quote indents are created by the receiving mail app.  The actual underlying code is always ">", ">>", etc. So I don't think it matters at the other end if you are only seeing the latter when you are composing.

Comment: Hi Tom, that's not my experience. For example, in some cases, especially when replying to rich text using rich text, I see a mixture of vertical line quote indents *and* ">". Then things get screwed up.

Comment: I thought you were asking about replying using plain text.  Perhaps it would be good to post a screen shot of what you are seeing when you switch to plain text before you reply, etc.

Comment: (Isn't it a pity that we have to specify cake.)

Comment: If you could link to a specific email you want help parsing, that might help. Sadly, rich text and html encoding ads so much complexity that a general purpose plug in is not available. I'll share my solution as an answer - but it's more a workaround and not a true all-powerful gadget that can fix all emails.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen a good universal solution, but have found that by selecting only the bare minimum text I need to reply to, I can often get a clean, clear reply that doesn't need substantial (or even any) clean up when replying in plain text.

Sadly, the best solution for presenting these emails cleanly is a powerful email client like [elm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elm_%28email_client%29). BBedit, Safari's reader and Coda 2 are all in my toolchain for taking a complicated HTML document and thinning it down but it's awkward to send the text to a second program, operate on the document and then get it back into a reply using Mail.

I wish I could serve you up a delicious cake of a plug in, but sadly, the Mail plug in scene isn't lucrative and this use case doesn't have a champion that's programming a better converter than the one Apple has provided.

Of the reviews of plug-ins, these are the best:

- http://www.tikouka.net/mailapp/
- http://www.macworld.com/product/collection/6866/mailaddons.html

And if [QuoteFix](http://www.macworld.com/article/1154707/quotefix_for_mail.html) won't work for you, you may have to program this yourself. It might do the trick by deleting trailing spaces, but without a sample of your mail in question, it's hard to tell.

Comment: +1 for QuoteFix. I usually set it to quote only the last email to keep replies/forwards clean and use the **Show related messages** features when I need to track the message history. That along with composing in plain text only, the way I think mail was meant to be (although I may be part of a minority), makes e-mailing quite productive.